# How to find Disk usage in UNIX?

Tags: bash, unix, du

I need to find the disk usage within a directory for only specific files eg. *2013_04* in UNIX.

Thanks!

LP

Comment: **Possible duplicate:**  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9485981/970195

Comment: I don't think that answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/9485981/970195 really matches my question but thanks anyway

Comment: Got the answer; it's simply ducs *pattern* :)